# Using webdriver plugin in jmeter

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter

Iam trying to use webdriver plugin to automate an application in jmeter. Can anyone help me to do scripting in selenium by using webdriver plugin. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the browser and programming language you're using.

Currently Chrome is the most popular browser and JavaScript is the default language for the WebDriver Sampler so:

1. Download [chromedriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/) (make sure that the version you download matches your Chrome browser version)
2. Add [Chrome Driver Config](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ChromeDriverConfig/) and specify the path to the chromedriver in the "Chrome" tab:

   [image]
3. Add [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) and implement the code for your test scenario. `WDS.browser` will stand for the [ChromeDriver](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriver.html) instance so you will be able to: use

   - `WDS.browser.get('some url')` - open a page
   - `var element = WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id('some id'))` - locate a [WebElement](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html)
   - `element.click()` - click the element found in the previous step
   - etc.

More information: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered)